# Does .NET Hashtable uses the specialized Font equality comparer when fonts are used as keys?

Tags: c#, fonts, hashtable, equality, iequalitycomparer

I need to create a set of unique [Font](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.font) objects each of which should have an associated object. This should be done in a .NET Framework WinForms app. These Font objects come from various sources, and different Font objects can be actually the same - if they have the same name, size, and other characteristics. It seems the [Hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable) class can be used for this. Here is a simple test in a brand new WinForms app for .NET Framework:

```c#
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Font font1 = new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
    Font font2 = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25f);
    Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
    ht.Add(font1, 1);
    ht.Add(font2, 2);
}
```

The last statement that adds font2 throws the following exception:

> System.ArgumentException   HResult=0x80070057   Message=Item has
> already been added. Key in dictionary: '[Font: Name=Microsoft Sans
> Serif, Size=8.25, Units=3, GdiCharSet=1, GdiVerticalFont=False]'  Key
> being added: '[Font: Name=Microsoft Sans Serif, Size=8.25, Units=3,
> GdiCharSet=1, GdiVerticalFont=False]'   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
> at System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert(Object key, Object nvalue,
> Boolean add)    at System.Collections.Hashtable.Add(Object key, Object
> value)    at Font_Hashtable.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs
> e)

This proves that the specialized Font equality comparer is used to check if Font objects are used as Hashtable keys. I wonder - can we really use a Hashtable for this scenario? As I know, .NET Hashtables should compare keys by references if they are objects, and there should be no exception in the code above if this is the case.

Comment: *As I know, .NET Hashtables should compare keys by references if they are objects* **no,  they are not**  (well,not only)... they depend on `GetHashCode` and `Equals` ... so the fact that some fonts are "the same" lies in Font's implementation of those methods

Comment: https://source.dot.net/#System.Drawing.Common/System/Drawing/Font.cs,228

Comment: ... which Ralf provides

Comment: Why you still use the ancient `Hashtable` instead of a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`?

Comment: @Ralf, I saw the internal of the redefined Equals method of the Font class. The question was whether it is used by the Hashtable implementation.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, does the redefined Font.Equals method will be used by Dictionary the same way as by Hashtable?

Comment: It is used unless you provide your own comparer via  the constructor.

Comment: @TecMan: Yes, similar. The dictionary will check if there is an item with the same hashcode and if so if both are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Hashtable` [checks in `Add` if the key is already contained](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/hashtable.cs,da0930441edd163b), then it will throw this exception. Therefore it checks if there is one with the same hashcode. If so it checks if they are equal, first by checking if it's the same same reference([`object.ReferenceEquals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.referenceequals?view=net-7.0)). If not it checks if they are equal. Either by the [given `KeyComaprer` in the constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-collections-hashtable-ctor(system-collections-idictionary-system-single-system-collections-iequalitycomparer)) or by `object.Equals`. If `Equals` is overridden, [`Font` overrides `Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.font.equals?view=windowsdesktop-7.0), that one is used.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-collections-hashtable-ctor(system-collections-idictionary-system-single-system-collections-iequalitycomparer)) mentions it also:

> "The default hash code provider is each key's implementation of
> GetHashCode() and the default comparer is each key's implementation of
> Equals(Object)."

Since `GetHashCode` is used first, always override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` together. Two equal objects must have the same hashcode(but same hashcode doesn't necessarily mean equal).

---

By the way, there is no reason to use the old `Hashtable` anymore. Here you should use a `Dictionary<Font, float>`.

If you use a `HashTable` or a generic `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` does not make a difference for this issue: both are checking in [`Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.add?view=net-7.0) if there is another item with the same hash-code and if so, if both items are equal, then you get this `ArgumentException`.

Both use either the passed custom `IEqalityComparer`([constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-collections-hashtable-ctor(system-int32-system-single-system-collections-iequalitycomparer))) or `Equals`(if not overridden [`object.Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=net-7.0), which just compares references).